# Are the Cloud Vision API limits in documentation correct?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I cross posted this to the google group for Cloud Vision...
and have added some additional findings.

Here are all of the specifics I believe are relevant:

- Using VB.NET 2010
- Using service account authentication
- Limited to .NET 4.0
- Using these Google libs: Google.Api  v1.10.0, Google.Apis.Auth v1.10.0, Google.Apis.Vision.v1  v1.12.0.45
- Performing Text and Safe Search Analysis
- Passing image content in request (not using Google Drive)

When just sending through 4 images or so per request, things work as expected... I get responses, and annotations.

If I up the number of images to 8 files per request,   The response back from Execute contains no results..  No errors, no exceptions either.

Just a Google.Apis.Vision.v1.Data.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse object with zero responses.   Using a network traffic monitoring tool, I see the connection to google vision - and the service returns a 200 server response.  But is otherwise empty.

Further research showed that I'm able to successfully send about a total 1MB of base64 content to the API per overall request  Anything more, I get the odd condition described.

According to the API documentation, the following limits apply to Google Cloud Vision API usage.

I'm not seeing any way I could be breaking the documented limits:    8 files per each request, total way less than 8MB, and no file even close to 4MB.

Any thoughts as to what I might be missing?  Are the documented limitations below correct?

- MB per image 4 MB
- MB per request 8 MB
- Requests per second 10
- Requests per feature per day 700,000
- Requests per feature per month 20,000,000
- Images per second 8
- Images per request 16

Comment: The more I play with this, the more it seems that there is a problem with the .NET Google vision API targetting .NET 4.0 (at least).

I took the same credentials, and the example python script from the google cloud vision api samples and was able to process a large file.

Comment: Sorry for not responding before; I've only just seen this. Have you tried using the gRPC-based client library? See https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1/index.html

Comment: And are you still able to reproduce the problem? It would *really* help if you could provide a [mcve] so that we could try to work out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, there is a bug in Google's implementation of gzip compression on the request...  I'm not sure if the API only applies gzip compression when the request size hits a certain threshold, or if the implementation bugs works for small requests, but not for large ones.

Here is how I solved my problem (Disabling GZIP is the key):

```
    Private Function GetAnalysisService() As VisionService
        Dim credential As GoogleCredential = Nothing

        credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefaultAsync().Result

        If credential.IsCreateScopedRequired Then
            credential = credential.CreateScoped(New String()  {VisionService.Scope.CloudPlatform})
        End If

        Dim ServiceInitializer = New VisionService.Initializer With {.ApplicationName = "TF Image Analysis", .HttpClientInitializer = credential}

        ServiceInitializer.GZipEnabled = False

        Return New VisionService(ServiceInitializer)
    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for doing the legwork on this one and posting your findings, Mike!!!

Google engineers: 5 months later and still no fix?

Comment: I can't remember whether we've made any changes to gzip since this was first posted, but I've used it with Google Cloud Storage for ages without any problems. The fact that disabling gzip solves the problem doesn't mean the problem is with the implementation of gzip (which is just the one in .NET, btw - haven't reimplemented it ourselves). It may be a problem with how the Vision service interacts with gzip, for example. It would really be useful to be able to reproduce this...

Answer (score 0):

I also wonder if the limits are correct.

Based on [Quotas and Limits](https://cloud.google.com/vision/quotas) and [Supported Images](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files), the maximum image file size should be **20 MB** for images hosted on Cloud Storage or at a publicly-accessible URL. Also there is maximum JSON request object size (10 MB).

I'm using option with images hosted on Cloud Storage, but for images larger than ~7.95 MB (12000 x 6500) I'm getting an error message:

```
responses {
  error {
    code: 3
    message: "Invalid image contents: gs://... ."
  }
}
```

For images with lower size I'm getting correct response.